# Dependency not appearing in dependency tree but there in pom

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

mvn dependency:tree produces an output that doesn't contain
The pom.xml has the following explicit dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.6</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I run mvn dependency:tree in the project, the output doesn't contain jackson-databind dependency.
Could this be because of a parent pom included at the top :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>net.xyz.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.6</version>
<relativePath/>
</parent>
```

But I checked the parent pom, and there is no dependency tag. Only the plugins

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the dependency is inside `<dependencyManagement>`.

Comment: Yeah, it's included inside dependencyManagement tag. I will read up on that. Is it probably something to do with parent pom?

Comment: No, move it to the `<dependencies>` section outside `<dependencyManagement>` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was super cool!